# What effect does rotation in the spatial domain has on phase in Fourier transforms?

Tags: fourier-transform, phase

More precisely, let's say I apply a 45 degrees rotation to an image (in the spatial domain) say, in Matlab :

```
Ir=imrotate(myImage,45,'crop');
FT_I=fft2(I);
```

In the magnitude, i.e. abs(FT_I) is it clear that the spectrum has be rotated too.

For example, trying to reconstruct/sort of "unrotate", wrt center (with shifted DC in center), in the frequency domaine like:

```
FT_Is=fftshift(FT_I);
I_rec_FT=abs(ifftshift(imrotate(FT_Is,45,'crop'))).*exp(-i*angle(ifftshift(imrotate(FT_Is,-45,'crop'))));
```

...does not make sense (ifft2()) does not show an image that seems at all sort of unrotated.

Therefore, what exactly happens with the ***phase*** part?

[image]

"unrotated" unsuccessfully, image.

[image]

From these spectra, one can clearly see that the magnitude spectrum has been rotated by the same amount. However, the phase has a random character, and one cannot visually see anything (from the phase image). I would like to know what mathematically and intuitively happens with the phase?

Moreover, it is mentioned in this lecture that rotation in spatial (or temporal) domain results in rotation in frequency domain, by the same angle, but unfortunately no precision are given w.r.t. the phase.

[image]

Moreover its stated in this lecture of Verona University and I heard it from image processing professors...

http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid916567.pdf

https://www.slideshare.net/chinnannanperiasamy/fourier-transform-44374579

Comment: "it's clear the spectrum has been rotated, too": How is that clear?

Comment: by looking at the magnitude image

Comment: Um, could you explain that? Maybe with a picture?

Comment: yes I just added the spectra, please look at them. I did a 90 degrees rotation this time because i think its easier to see.

Comment: Can you really go ahead and try with a 45° rotation. It doesn't work with any rotation that's not a multiple of 90°. I was wondering whether I was misunderstanding you, but this showed that you're under a misconception.

Comment: but look at this please :https://www.slideshare.net/chinnannanperiasamy/fourier-transform-44374579 they clearly state the equivalence of rotation in spatial = rotation in freq

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Can't open that, but if they claim that, they're plain wrong.

Comment: Now can open that. I can't even find where they claim that. In fact, the pictures they choose (e.g. slide 32) say something different.

Comment: I posted the aforementioned picture ... can you not see the rotated object and rotated spectrum? How would you interpret that then?

Comment: or even here (p.3) https://www.eee.hku.hk/~work8501/WWW2008/ho4.pdf

Comment: And it would be a bad idea to close this topic, as precisely this DFT rotation property in found in almost any Fourier lectures and it should be discussed since people seem not to understand it

Comment: Yeah, agreed, taking that back.

Comment: OK, apologies accepted. My interest is in science not argument :)

Comment: maybe you can help me understand how to implement a rotation in the frequency domain? (then I would ifft2 it back to the spatial domain to check if it works)

Comment: I described that below: Pad your image with a lot of zeros to each side. You're simply seeing the circular behaviour of the DFT. That's expected! If you want a spatial rotation without padding, do it in spatial domain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has a simpler answer for the 2-D continuous-space Fourier transform but itsdDiscrete Fourier transform based verification requires some elaboration and careful implementation as @MarcusMüller has already mentioned.

On the continuous-space it can be shown that rotating an image $f(x,y)$ by $\theta$ radians CCW (counter-clock wise) on the $xy$ plane, will also rotate the corresponding CSFT (continuous-space Fourier transform) $F( \Omega_1 , \Omega_2 )$ by $\theta$ radians CCW :

CCW rotation by $\theta$ on the $xy$ plane can be described by the following transform:

$$
x' = x \cos(\theta) - y \sin(\theta) \\
y' = x \sin(\theta) + y \cos(\theta) \tag{1}
$$

where $x,y$ are the original coordinates and $x',y'$ are the rotated (new) coordinates. A corresponding *inverse* rotation by $\theta$, (or CCW by $-\theta$ ) has the following transform :

$$
x = + x' \cos(\theta) + y' \sin(\theta)  \tag{2} \\
y = - x' \sin(\theta) + y' \cos(\theta) 
$$

Given the original image $f(x,y)$, we rotate it CCW by $\theta$ to obtain the rotated image $g_r(x,y)$, then the following will hold :

$$ g_r(x,y) = f( x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta) , - x \sin(\theta) + y \cos(\theta) ) \tag{3} $$

Note that in Eq. (3), the arguments of the original function $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ are described by the *inverse* rotation relation to coordinates $x,y$ of $g_r(\cdot,\cdot)$.

The CSFT of the rotated image $g_r(x,y)$ is:

$$
\boxed{ G_r(\Omega_1,\Omega_2) = \iint_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_r(x,y) e^{-j( \Omega_1 x + \Omega_2 y) } dx dy} \\
$$

$$
\begin{align} 
&= \iint f( x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta) , - x \sin(\theta) + y \cos(\theta) ) e^{-j( \Omega_1 x + \Omega_2 y) }   \tag{4} \\
&= \iint f( x' , y' ) e^{-j[ \Omega_1 (x' \cos(\theta) - y'\sin(\theta)) + \Omega_2 (x' \sin(\theta) + y' \cos(\theta)) ]} dx' dy'  \tag{5}\\
&= \iint f( x' , y' ) e^{-j[ ( \Omega_1 \cos(\theta) + \Omega_2  \sin(\theta) ) x' + (-\Omega_1 \sin(\theta) + \Omega_2 \cos(\theta)) y' ]} dx' dy'  \tag{6}\\
&= F(  \Omega_1 \cos(\theta) + \Omega_2  \sin(\theta) ,   -\Omega_1 \sin(\theta) + \Omega_2 \cos(\theta) ) \tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

In moving from step (4) to (5), make the substitution defined in Eqs (1) and (2), and note that the Jacobian of the transformation is unity. See page 778 of Calculus Adams 6E for an explanation and derivation of this result.

In moving from step (6) to (7) we simply recognise the expression in Eq.(6) as the CSFT of the original signal $f(x,y)$ with arguments given according to relation in Eq.(3) given as below:

$$G_r(\Omega_1,\Omega_2) = F(  \Omega_1 \cos(\theta) + \Omega_2  \sin(\theta) ,   -\Omega_1 \sin(\theta) + \Omega_2 \cos(\theta) ) \tag{8} $$

Eq.(8) is analogous to Eq.(3) and states that the CSFT of the rotated image is also roated by the same amount;  $\theta$ CCW. This, therefore, means that **phase** is also rotated by the same amount.

Verification of this result within the discrete-space sequences $f[n,m]$ and their corresponding DFT sequences requires specific care given to potential **aliasing** caused by inadequate sampling of the rotated image $g_r(x,y)$, and  proper **circular** extension of the rotated sequence $g_r[n,m]$.

Without going into mathematical details, I'll put the results of the following implementation of the rotation using Matlab/ Octave (rotation is wrt upper left corner)

[image]

We can still see artefacts of non-ideal implementation...

Note that with typical images it's harder to realize the ideal result.

Comment: interesting answer thanks, i will read it ASAP.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. However, I am surprised that in all lectures I've had so far, nothing was mentioned about the artifacts with the DFT.

Comment: yes because it will be quite complicated to do so...

Comment: Hum, it is always a but frustrating when the theory does not exactly coincide with practice. Maybe a bit like when Obi-Wan Kenobi said to Luke Skywalker that his father was killed by Darth Vader (cf. episode 4), but then in fact it was a metaphor, and not the practical truth.

Comment: hmm that's a nice metaphor... Unfortunately the discrete-space domain does not permit rotations on the sequence unless it's **re-sampled** from its continuous space interpolation. And these are non-perfect operations in practice, hence it's quite hard to realize it in practice...

Comment: In fact I m not sure I completely understand your proof. Could you please develop a bit step (4) especially could you add the dx dy or the d(?)d(?) since I m not always sure ... can you add some comments about these ? In fact : why would we have $\Omega_1 x+ \Omega_2 y$ rather than $\Omega_1 xcos(\theta)+y sin(\theta) ...$ etc...+ \Omega_2 y$ in the complex exponential in (4)?

Comment: it's $dxdy$ but line was too long to fit and I thought reader could infer from the variable of the arguments.. In fact Eq.4 is a copy of the boxed formula between Eq.3 and Eq.4;  I have only replaced $g_r(x,y)$ by the $f(x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta) , -x \sin(\theta) + y \cos(\theta) $, but the exponential is still the same at the 4'th step.

Comment: Thanks. Although I have dealt with integration in the past, I suddenly seem to have a problem here, when it comes to understanding why we are allowed to make certain variable substitutions. I know of course that it is a "continuous double summation" in directions x and y; I understand that x and y are allowed to be replaced in $g_r(x,y)$ by $f(xcos(\theta)+...)$ because of eq. (3) and you have defined these args to be x' and y' so you can subs them in (5). But my problem is:when you write in (5) integration wrt $dx'dy'$ does that mean you are integrating wrt a rotated coordinate system for f ?

Comment: And what do you mean by Jacobian of the transform? (I know the Jacobian is a matrix of 1st order partial derivatives, but could you develop here (how do you formulate the transform (rotation I guess!) wrt which vars etc), (would be really great !).

Comment: or are you/also using the integration rule called u-substitution?

Comment: I can imagine this would be related to the Jacobian in some way since the u-subst involves writing the integral wrt the derivative of a composite function. (sorry for all the comments but in order to understand I would need all the steps even if they may seem obvious to you, I find integration to be quite a hard - although very interesting - topic)

Comment: yes your interpretation is right. In effect you are integrating the rotated function in a rotated coordinate system with a phase rotated exponential kernel wrt to the rotated coordinates, the Jacobian of this rotation is unity so that $dxdy = dx'dy'$ ...

Comment: thanks for your very fast answers. May I ask you to write - even in an abbreviated form if you prefer -  this Jacobian? I m not sure I see why the unity Jacobian implies that $dxdy$ = $dx'dy'$ (and is it related to u-subst ?)

Comment: (like that, I can write this down once-and-for all somewhere and go back to it with all the detailed steps if needed)

Comment: Also, isn't there a typo in (5) ? If (as I understand) you subst. x and y with their forumlation in terms of x' and y' from (2). Would it not rather be $e^{-j[ \Omega_1 (x' \cos(\theta) + y'\sin(\theta)) + \Omega_2 (-x' \sin(\theta) + y' \cos(\theta)) ]}$ rather than

$e^{-j[ \Omega_1 (x' \cos(\theta) - y'\sin(\theta)) + \Omega_2 (x' \sin(\theta) + y' \cos(\theta)) ]}$ ?

Comment: it's the **determinant** of the Jacobain which is unity, not the Jacobain matrix, sorry if this casued confusion... I changed the variables of th integral in Eq.4 and obtained theone in Eq.5; the differential areas are related by the determinant of the Jacobain of the variable substitution. That determinant is one.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Calculus Adams 6E. No my confusion is rather between the change of basis (multiplication with inverse chg basis matrix) and the CW/CCW rotations... it s like thinking backwards ... very confusing unfortunately

Comment: Calculus Adams 6E (i ve been able to find the 7th edition free in pdf, hope i can find it there although not on same page)

Comment: I also found (this same proof) at https://www.eee.hku.hk/~work8501/WWW2008/ho4.pdf where they mention such a unity determinant Jacobian p.3 with a slightly different approach as you although it comes down to the same thing I suppose ? (However, I find a bit confusing this change of basis because it seems your x' y' are like defined in the reverse way as their x~ y~ ?

Comment: Adams **7E page 812-3** shows the procedure of change of variables and the resulting determinant of Jacobians for double integrals. I don't want to put the procedure here because it's not only long but also not related to the question. But you are right, my notation is a little obscure. However there are only two transforms; one is the CCW rotation by $\theta$ and the other is its inverse. Just adjust your interpretation of variables and the corresponding transforms on them irrespective of $x,y,x'y'$. And btw since |J| = 1, just concentrate of the arguments of the function and the exponential.

Comment: Ok, so the Jacobian J = $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{dx'}{dx} \frac{dy'}{dx} \\ \frac{dx'}{dy} \frac{dy'}{dy} \end{pmatrix}$ and taking the $x'$ and $y'$ you have defined in (1) and if I derived them wrt x and wrt y I get the following Jacobian: J=$\begin{pmatrix} cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\ -sin(\theta) &  cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}$ and $det(J)=1$ due to a trig indentity, and this implies that $dx'dy'=dxdy*det(J)=dxdy*1=dxdy$, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes,  this is it ..!

Comment: Grenat, thanks. Juste to add 1 more thing: can we say that the dx'dy' are an infinitesimal surface element wrt a rotated  coordinate system of basis vectors having directions x' y' and of the same infinitesimal area as dxdy ?

Comment: ok yes.. but I think you should ask "these" questions to **math.se** instead of **dsp.se**...

Comment: Ok I will post a related question on math

Comment: I ve added a question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354981/integration-methods-and-properties maybe you want to answer it ? ;) (sorry for posting here, but AFAIK there is no direct chat between users here ?

Comment: I have a challenging question for you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/how-to-implement-interpolation-by-convolution-for-rotation-of-an-image-by-an-ang

Comment: @SheppLogan right now it's too challenging for me...

Answer (score 0):

You're under a misconception:

> I apply a 45 degrees rotation to an image (in the spatial domain), …
>   clear that the spectrum has be rotated too.

If you rotate an image $K$ by an angle $\alpha$, say we call the rotation operation $R_\alpha(K): \mathbb R^{w\times h}\mapsto \mathbb R^{w\times h}$, the $\text{DFT}\left(R_\alpha(K)\right)\ne R_\alpha\left(\text{DFT}(K)\right)$.

That's easy to see. Assuming an image $K$ that's completely 0 but for a single pixel, straight in the middle of the image. Then, for any angle $\alpha$, $R_\alpha(K)=K$, i.e. the image is invariant to rotation.

It's DFT is not: It's a vertical/horizontal cross. Rotating that cross yields a different image that is not the same as the original. The spectrum is not invariant to rotation. Hence, the statement that rotation of spatial domain is equivalent to rotation of frequency domain must be false.

The difference is that it's important how large (especially: finite) your image is. If it's infinite, then the rotation argument holds, but then that's not a property of the 2D-DFT (==2D-FFT), because that assumes finite images.

The pictures you're showing aren't *correct* in the narrow sense of the word:

> [image]

I tried to reproduce that, and as predicted, *it doesn't look like your literature*:

[image: reproduction]

*From top to bottom, left to right: Original image, rotated by 50°; |DFT| logarithmic (because otherwise hard to see at all) of original image, of rotated image.*

Why? Probably because these slides were done by physicists confusing a narrow excerpt of the output of Fourier optics with a DFT.

You'll notice that in the DFT of the rotated image, you get "crosses" in the corners of the image. That's the circular nature of the DFT at work!

Comment: Then how do you interpret slide 1 DFT properties rotation: (i hope you can read PDF files?): http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid916567.pdf

Comment: or here (p3) https://www.eee.hku.hk/~work8501/WWW2008/ho4.pdf : "In words, that means an anti-clockwise rotation of a function by an angleθimplies that its Fouriertransform is also rotated anti-clockwise by the same angle"

Comment: Hehe, they're omitting that the signal is finite! What you write is correct, but only if you think of finitely large images padded in an infinitely large plane of zeros!

Comment: I m not sure I understand what you mean. However, my question is: can you formulate mathematically what happends to the phase? I mean is a +theta angle added to it for example?

Comment: Not uniformly, no. I think this might help. Pad your image to all sides with say 10 times the image size of zeros. Apply the DFT; observe the effect of zero padding. Now cut the DFT to its original size, IDFT. Observe the *aliasing* you're getting. Now, experiment with rotations: Observe how the limitation to finite image sizes always leads to circular operations and aliasing.

Comment: I created another related but different question (I hope people won't be angry at me for that) but I think it is very interesting, look how the cameraman is indeed rotated but a dark band appears: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60021/implementing-rotation-in-frequency-domain-and-map-it-back-to-spatial-domain

Comment: I have a challenging question for you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/how-to-implement-interpolation-by-convolution-for-rotation-of-an-image-by-an-ang