# Implementing rotation in frequency domain and map it back to spatial domain

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

Please consider the following small example:

```
x=im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
X=fft2(x);

Xr=imrotate(fftshift(X),90);

xRec=ifft2(ifftshift(Xr));

figure;
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(x);
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(xRec);
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(log(fftshift(abs(X))+1),[]);
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(fftshift(log(abs(fft2(xRec))+1)),[]);

%magnitudes of both have same total energy
sum(sum(abs(X)))-sum(sum(abs(Xr)))
```

the result xRec is indeed rotated by 90 degrees when reconstructed from rotated Fourier domain, but a dark band appears in the center. Can someone help me to implemented in the correct manner? The goal is of course to show the Fourier rotation property. That rotation in one domain is equivalent to rotation in the other.

[image]

even more interesting, if i remove the ifftshift I almost get my rotated cameraman but with artefacts !
[image]

also some trick with polar coordinates is mentioned here (slide 22) ... but I would need help ...

https://www.kth.se/social/upload/528393f5f276545b305c8dfd/13_lecture05b.pdf

Comment: is the original image square?

Comment: yes it is 256*256

Comment: i ve also tried padding it like x=padarray(x,[256 256]); but then result is black but same (visually I mean) spectrum (rotated)

Comment: and look what happens if I remove the ifftshift... I get him rotated indeed but with artefacts ... why ?!

Comment: These artifacts seem periodic however, and I wonder if some kind of interpolation is needed ...or something like that ... but why and how ...it seems quite a difficult problem?

Comment: Some thoughts: Have you checked that the phase is not altered? You checked the energy, but the phase could be corrupted due to some interpolation of imrotate. Also: What is the data type that imrotate processes? Is it float, or are you loosing precision due to a reduction from float to int or something like that? Have you tried to convert the image to float before the FFT?

You could also try to check what happens if you transpose the image - then there should be no interpolation involved.

Comment: Nice hints thanks I will try these and report back my results. (but transpose is like a symmetry though)

Comment: This: sum(sum(angle(fft2(x))))-sum(sum(angle(fft2(xRec)))) shows that phases of  fourier transform of xRec are inverted.The value is +12.56 (same value of 6.25 but one neg one pos) However sum(sum(angle(X)))-sum(sum(angle(Xr))) have same phases (e-13 negligable diff). So its like if there was a problem at reconstruction ! ? I dont understant why

Comment: maybe a "trick" involving polar coords: https://www.kth.se/social/upload/528393f5f276545b305c8dfd/13_lecture05b.pdf slide 22 ...?