# Numerically observe the rotation property of the Fourier transform

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, python, dft

I would like to numerically observe the rotation property of the Fourier transform. I believe that it is not possible since the rotation property is for the continuous transform and the [DFT introduces an aliasing problem due to imperfect sampling of the input](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60061/65151) and also [has a circular nature](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60019/65151).

From the [rotation property](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-4613-1333-5/1.pdf), for a rotation $\mathcal T$, $\mathcal T\mathcal F f = \mathcal F \mathcal T f$. Thus, if $f$ is symmetric to $\mathcal T$, i.e., $\mathcal T f = f$, then the rotation property implies that the transform of $f$ is symmetric to $\mathcal T$ as well, i.e., $\mathcal T\mathcal F f = \mathcal F f$.

Further, if $f$ is real, it's transform $\mathcal F f$ will be Hermitian, and along with the rotation property, this implies that $\mathcal F f$ will be real-valued, e.g., [the Gaussian function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html) (proof sketch below).

However, neither of these properties are apparent numerically, presumably due to the previously mentioned issues. Here, I am choosing $\mathcal T$ to be a $90^\circ$ rotation.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
f = np.random.randn(5, 5)
f = sum([np.rot90(f, k=k) for k in range(4)])
f.round(1)
Out[2]: 
array([[ 2.3, -1.5,  3. , -1.6,  2.3],
       [-1.6,  1.9, -4.1,  1.9, -1.5],
       [ 3. , -4.1, -1.3, -4.1,  3. ],
       [-1.5,  1.9, -4.1,  1.9, -1.6],
       [ 2.3, -1.6,  3. , -1.5,  2.3]])
np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(f)).round(1)
Out[3]: 
array([[-19.9-14.5j,  -2.7 -8.2j,   1.4 -4.4j,   7.7 -5.6j,  24.6 +0.j ],
       [ -2.9 -9.1j,  -1.9 +5.8j,  10.3 -7.5j,  -6.1 +0.j ,   6.9 +5.j ],
       [  1.4 -4.4j,  10.3 -7.5j,  -1.3 +0.j ,  10.3 +7.5j,   1.4 +4.4j],
       [  6.9 -5.j ,  -6.1 +0.j ,  10.3 +7.5j,  -1.9 -5.8j,  -2.9 +9.1j],
       [ 24.6 -0.j ,   7.7 +5.6j,   1.4 +4.4j,  -2.7 +8.2j, -19.9+14.5j]])
```

I also tried adding a large amount of 0 padding to see if either of these properties begins to become apparent on a "less" finite domain to try and mitigate the circular nature of the transform:

```
f = np.pad(f, (10000, 10000))
sum([np.abs(f - np.rot90(f, k=k)) for k in range(4)]).sum() # still symmetric
Out[4]: 5.329070518200751e-15
F = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(f))
np.abs(np.rot90(F) - F).mean() # not symmetric
Out[5]: 12.827504372261783
np.abs(F.imag).mean() # imaginary part not 0
Out[6]: 4.852261405894498
```

Finally, I tried with the radially symmetric Gaussian function.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.concatenate([x[None] for x in np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)] * 2)])
y = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(x, axis=0))
np.abs(y - np.rot90(y)).sum() # symmetric
Out[2]: 2.091662961614887e-10
Y = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(y))
np.abs(Y - np.rot90(Y)).mean() # not symmetric
Out[3]: 1.9977764482822713
np.abs(Y.imag).mean() # imaginary part not 0
Out[4]: 0.006017917416468471
```

Is it possible to numerically observe the desired results?

Sketch: If $h:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C$ is Hermitian and symmetric to rotations, then it is real-valued (i.e., imaginary part is $0$).

Since $h$ is symmetric to rotations, $h(x,y) = h(-x, -y)$, which implies that $\Im h(x,y)=\Im h(-x,-y)$, where $h=\Re h + i\Im h$.

Next, since $h$ is Hermitian, $\Im h(x,y)=-\Im h(-x,-y)$. Thus, $\Im h(-x,-y) = -\Im h(-x,-y)=0$, and so $\Im h(x,y)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I talk about the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) here, remember that the FFT is just an *algorithm* to realize the DFT -- so I'm talking about the FFT, too.

The usual way that the DFT is expressed has slightly weird indexing, and the way that is translated into matrices has *really* weird indexing.  Undwinding this for the purposes of rotating 2D Fourier transforms is something that I find to be a combination of "well duh, that's obvious", and hours spent screaming at my computer while I get *all* of the 'i's dotted correctly, 't's crossed correctly, dotted 't's and crossed 'i's sorted out, etc.

The reason for this is that we usually start the indexing at the beginning of the sequence; there is no "negative" index.  But when you start talking about rotating the input and output of the Fourier transform, you need to rotate it around the origin.

Remember that while the DFT is usually performed on vectors, the underlying math is performing its work on functions of time (or space) and frequency.  Remember further that a length $N$ DFT *does not change* if you shift the time index by $N$ -- this is a direct consequence of the trigonometric identities $\cos \theta = \cos \theta + 2 \pi$ and $\sin \theta = \sin \theta + 2 \pi$.

In other words, the DFT works for $x(n)$ defined over *any* interval that is $N$ points long, as long as you define $x(n) = x(n + Nk)\, \forall\, k \in \mathbb I$.

Take the 1D case.  When you "rotate" x(n) by 180$^\circ$, you need to reflect it *around $n = 0$*.  This means that $x'(0) = x(0)$, $x'(1) = x(-1)$, etc.  *But the traditional indexing doesn't have an $x(-1)$*.  So instead, you need to calculate the indexing as $x'(0) = x(0)$, $x'(1) = x(N-1)$, etc..  This is where you start screaming at the screen...

This means that the vector $x = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$, when rotated 180$^\circ$ *for the discrete Fourier transform* needs to end up as $x' = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

The case is similar, but more complicated, for 2D rotations.  It **just doesn't match** the Numpy 'rot90' function (although you can wedge that into the scheme for $N \in \mathcal I^{\mathrm {odd}}$).  I *strongly suggest* that you sketch out all four 90$^\circ$ rotations.

As an example, if you start with

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
00 & 01 & 02 \\ 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 20 & 21 & 22
\end{bmatrix}$$

then a 90 degree rotation rotates most of your matrix "out of the frame":

$$X' = \begin{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
02 & 12 & 22 \\ 01 & 11 & 21
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
00 & 10 & 20 \\
 \\ \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
$$
Which, in its screwy way, really means:

$$ X' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
00 & 10 & 20 \\ 02 & 12 & 22 \\ 01 & 11 & 21 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

For the purposes of coding this, as mentioned, you can use Numpy `fftshift` *if $N$ is odd*, but you need to shift, then rotate, then shift back -- **and** it's not going to work for you for even $N$ -- for that, you need to make your own rotation function, or find one in the bowels of Numpy.

To demonstrate this:

```
>>> X = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5).astype(float); X -= X.mean()
>>> X
array([[-12., -11., -10.,  -9.,  -8.],
       [ -7.,  -6.,  -5.,  -4.,  -3.],
       [ -2.,  -1.,   0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.]])
>>> Xs = np.fft.fft2(X)
>>> Xs.round(1)
array([[  0.  +0.j , -12.5+17.2j, -12.5 +4.1j, -12.5 -4.1j, -12.5-17.2j],
       [-62.5+86.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ],
       [-62.5+20.3j,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ],
       [-62.5-20.3j,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ],
       [-62.5-86.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  +0.j ]])
>>> np.fft.fft2(np.fft.ifftshift(np.rot90(np.fft.fftshift(X), 1))).round(1)
array([[  0.  +0.j , -62.5+86.j , -62.5+20.3j, -62.5-20.3j, -62.5-86.j ],
       [-12.5-17.2j,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ],
       [-12.5 -4.1j,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ],
       [-12.5 +4.1j,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ],
       [-12.5+17.2j,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ]])
>>> np.fft.fft2(np.fft.ifftshift(np.rot90(np.fft.fftshift(X), 2))).round(1)
array([[  0.  +0.j , -12.5-17.2j, -12.5 -4.1j, -12.5 +4.1j, -12.5+17.2j],
       [-62.5-86.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  +0.j ],
       [-62.5-20.3j,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ],
       [-62.5+20.3j,  -0.  -0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ,  -0.  +0.j ],
       [-62.5+86.j ,   0.  -0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  +0.j ,   0.  -0.j ]])
```

Comment: How about for `X = np.concatenate([x[None] for x in np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)] * 2)]); X = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(X, axis=0))`? Since this is a rotation symmetric function and the sample has odd dimensions, I would expect that `Xs = np.fft.fft2(X); np.fft.fftshift(Xs)` would also be symmetric to rotations. Further, I know that the continuous transform of this Gaussian has an imaginary part equal to 0. Any ideas why we cannot observe either here?

Comment: I'm not making out what that code means -- sorry.  Is it symmetric _around $X_{1,1}$?_

Comment: `np.concatenate([x[None] for x in np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)] * 2)])` just creates Cartesian coordinates $\{(x,y):x,y\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}\}$. Then, `np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(X, axis=0))` gives the Gaussian function on these coordinates, which is symmetric about `0,0` (or the $(2,2)$ entry using matrix indexing)

Comment: OK -- you're not symmetric around the right spot.  Your resulting vector of indexes should be [0, 1, 2, -2, -1].  The _upper left corner_ of the matrix is zero-frequency (or zero position).  _That's_ what you have to index off of, or rotate around.